# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python

Не понимаю в чём ошибка?

```
for i in range(10000):
    print('\nВведите команду:')
    command = input()
    response = client.send_command(command)
    if command == '//wand':
        print('Комманда вводится в игре!')
    elif command == 'info':
        print('Команда вводится в игре!')
    elif command == 'tell':
        print('\nИспользуйте: tell ник_игрока сообщение')
    elif command == '/wand':
        print('Команда вводится в игре!')
    else:
        console = response.replace('§a', '').replace('§f', '').replace('§6', '').replace('§c', '').replace('/', '').replace('§5', '').replace('§d', '').replace('§r', '').replace('§4', '').replace('§7', '')
        print(console)
```

Comment: У объекта response нет метода replace

Comment: Точнее в переменной `replace` находится `None`, а не строка.

Comment: Вот ошибка:
console = response.replace('§a', '').replace('§f', '').replace('§6', '').replace('§c', '').replace('/', '').replace('§5', '').replace('§d', '').replace('§r', '').replace('§4', '').replace('§7', '')

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: Можете показать нам `.send_command()`?

Comment: это модуль import factorio_rcon

Comment: может так  console =command.replace('§a', '').replace('§f', '').replace('§6', '').replace('§c', '').replace('/', '').replace('§5', '').replace('§d', '').replace('§r', '').replace('§4', '').replace('§7', '')

Comment: Ага, ну так `client.send_command()` вам просто ничего не вернул, вот и все

Comment: krytoy4el - СПАСИБО!

Comment: Но мне нужно что бы значение response выводилось на экран

Comment: @krytoy4el Но мне нужно что бы значение response выводилось на экран

Answer (score 0):

```
console =command.replace('§a', '').replace('§f', '').replace('§6', '').replace('§c', '').replace('/', '').replace('§5', '').replace('§d', '').replace('§r', '').replace('§4', '').replace('§7', '')
```

Comment: Таким способом вы обработаете посланную команду, а не ответ сервера