# Вывод команды(ответа от сервера)

Tags: python

### Данный код просто выводит команду, а мне нужен ответ от сервера

Введите команду:

list - я ввёл

list - он вывел.

А должен был вывести:
Сейчас 1 из 50 игроков онлайн

```
for i in range(10000):
print('\nВведите команду:')
command = input()
client.send_command(command)
if command == '//wand':
    print('Команда вводится в игре!')
elif command == 'info':
    print('Команда вводится в игре!')
elif command == 'tell':
    print('\nИспользуйте: tell ник_игрока сообщение')
elif command == '/wand':
    print('Команда вводится в игре!')
else:
    console = command.replace('§a', '').replace('§f', '').replace('§6', '').replace('§c', '').replace('/', '').replace('§5', '').replace('§d', '').replace('§r', '').replace('§4', '').replace('§7', '')
    print(console)
```

Comment: А где же сервер??

Comment: Вы выводите переменную `console` которая получается просто обработкой строки `command`, а ответ сервера нигде не выводится. Ответ сервера возможно хранится внутри `client`, может в каком-то его свойстве. Что это за `client`, что он делает?

Answer (score 0):

У вас был [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1104868/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-replace/), в котором такой код:

```
for i in range(10000):
print('\nВведите команду:')
command = input()
response = client.send_command(command)
if command == '//wand':
    print('Комманда вводится в игре!')
elif command == 'info':
    print('Команда вводится в игре!')
elif command == 'tell':
    print('\nИспользуйте: tell ник_игрока сообщение')
elif command == '/wand':
    print('Команда вводится в игре!')
else:
    console = response.replace('§a', '').replace('§f', '').replace('§6', '').replace('§c', '').replace('/', '').replace('§5', '').replace('§d', '').replace('§r', '').replace('§4', '').replace('§7', '')
    print(console)
```

Он ближе к истине

Но переменная `response`- не строковая.

Заглянув на исходники [раз](https://github.com/mark9064/factorio-rcon-py), [два](https://github.com/mark9064/factorio-rcon-py/blob/master/factorio_rcon/factorio_rcon.py), я увидел, что переменная `response` имеет тип словаря, так как изначально она объявляется как `{}`

Например, если есть словарь `{'name':'John'}`, то код

```
d = {'name':'John'}
print(d['name'])
```

Выведет `John`

Можно вывести словарь красиво (если там не будет вложенных словарей):

```
response = client.send_command(command)
for a in response:
    print(f'{a}: {response[a]}')
```

Если надо еще прикрутить `replace`, то так:

```
response = client.send_command(command)
for a in response:
    print(f'{a}: {response[a]}'.replace('§a', '').replace('§f', '').replace('§6', '').replace('§c', '').replace('/', '').replace('§5', '').replace('§d', '').replace('§r', '').replace('§4', '').replace('§7', ''))
```

Чтобы просто тупо все вывести с `replace` можно так

```
console = str(response).replace('§a', '').replace('§f', '').replace('§6', '').replace('§c', '').replace('/', '').replace('§5', '').replace('§d', '').replace('§r', '').replace('§4', '').replace('§7', '')
print(console)
```